# Toolbar icon not being displayed in firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am writing a simple Firefox extension which has an icon in the toolbar. I am unable to add the toolbar icon using XUL. My file structure and code I am using is given below:

Extension:

```
-chrome.manifest
-install.rdf
-chrome
    -content
        -toolbarButton.js
        -toolbarButton.xul
    -locale
    -skin
        -toolbarButton.css
        -icon.png
```

chrome.manifest:

```
content myext chrome/content/
skin    myext   classic/1.0 chrome/skin/
locale    myext  en-US       chrome/locale/en-US/

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://myext/content/toolbarButton.xul

style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://myext/skin/toolbarButton.css
style chrome://global/content/browser.xul chrome://myext/skin/toolbarButton.css
```

XUL code:

```xml
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="toolbar-clipper-button"
      label="Some label"
      tooltiptext="Does something"
      oncommand="showMessage(event)" >
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

CSS code:

```css
#toolbar-clipper-button {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://myext/skin/toolbar-icon.png");
}
```

Please help me in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Please expand on "I am unable to add the toolbar icon". The code seems correct. Are you complaining about the button not showing up in the toolbar? It won't be added to any toolbars by default but it should show up in the [customization palette](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-customize-toolbars).

Comment: thanks, answer didn't help but question did :), i was missing 
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://myext/skin/toolbarButton.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the help of good folks in the mozilla community. Yes, I do not see the toolbar icon in the customize toolbar sheet. The issue was with packaging. All the files were not being copied in my case. The code works fine now...